# Filling a column with values from other rows with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Can someone please help me understand this?

Let us have this DataFrame:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "id": ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
    "parent_id": [None, None, 'a', 'b', 'a'],
    "name": ["Bob", "Jane", "John", "Patty", "Sam"],
})
```

Now, I want to retrieve the parent name next to each child name like this:

```
+----+-----------+-------+-------------+
| id | parent_id | name  | parent_name |
+----+-----------+-------+-------------+
| a  | None      | Bob   | NaN         |
+----+-----------+-------+-------------+
| b  | None      | Jane  | NaN         |
+----+-----------+-------+-------------+
| c  | a         | John  | Bob         |
+----+-----------+-------+-------------+
| d  | b         | Patty | Jane        |
+----+-----------+-------+-------------+
| e  | a         | Sam   | Bob         |
+----+-----------+-------+-------------+
```

So I do that:

```py
df['parent_name'] = None
df['parent_name'] = df['parent_id'].apply(lambda x: df['name'][df['id']==x])
```

But here's what I get:

```
+----+-----------+-------+-------------+
| id | parent_id | name  | parent_name |
+----+-----------+-------+-------------+
| a  | None      | Bob   | NaN         |
+----+-----------+-------+-------------+
| b  | None      | Jane  | NaN         |
+----+-----------+-------+-------------+
| c  | a         | John  | Bob         |
+----+-----------+-------+-------------+
| d  | b         | Patty | NaN         |
+----+-----------+-------+-------------+
| e  | a         | Sam   | Bob         |
+----+-----------+-------+-------------+
```

So, it appears to only process the first item in the `name` column.

In the words of Plato quoting Socrates: "WTF???"

Comment: @jezrael Are you sure the marked dupe is correct one? In this question there is only one dataframe not two. Maybe if you want to close it find better dupe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think how apply is used, you can use merge however:

```
df['parent_name'] = df[['parent_id']].merge(df[['id', 'name']], left_on=['parent_id'], right_on=['id'], how='left')['name']

#   id parent_id   name parent_name
# 0  a      None    Bob         NaN
# 1  b      None   Jane         NaN
# 2  c         a   John         Bob
# 3  d         b  Patty        Jane
# 4  e         a    Sam         Bob
```

Answer (score 3):

We can try [mapping](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) the `parent_id` with the corresponding `parent_name` based on common `id`

```
df['parent_name'] = df['parent_id'].map(df.set_index('id')['name'])
```

---

```
  id parent_id   name parent_name
0  a      None    Bob         NaN
1  b      None   Jane         NaN
2  c         a   John         Bob
3  d         b  Patty        Jane
4  e         a    Sam         Bob
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a merge

```py
final = df.merge(df[["id", "name"]].rename(
    columns={"name": "parent_name"}),
    left_on="parent_id",
    right_on="id",
    how="left"
)
```